# Pandoc error 4: could not determine bibliography format in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, bibtex

I have a .txt file exported from endnote with references that I am trying to insert to an r markdown document. The file is saved in my working directory with the title ref.bib.txt, but when I try to knit my r markdown file to a pdf, I get the following error:
Could not determine bibliography format for ref.bib.txt
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 4
Execution halted

Has anyone else encountered this error and if so how did you solve it?

Example reference:
@article{RN20,
author = {Fang, Yi-Ya and Yamaguchi, Takashi and Song, Soomin C and Tritsch, Nicolas
X and Lin, Dayu},
title = {A hypothalamic midbrain pathway essential for driving maternal behaviors},
journal = {Neuron},
volume = {98},
number = {1},
pages = {192-207. e10},
ISSN = {0896-6273},
year = {2018},
type = {Journal Article}

Comment: I get a somewhat more useful error "the format of the bibliographic database could not be recognized from the file extension".  What happens if you rename the file to `ref.bib` ... ??

Comment: Ah yep, that solved it thanks! At least its an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that pandoc tries to recognize bibliographic formats *by file extension*, so renaming the file to `ref.bib` should fix the problem.

(There are some settings on Windows/MacOS that hide file extensions, so this could be slightly confusing.)

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it.